# Cleaner ACL aros_acos table?

Tags: cakephp, acl

Everything seems to work as expected, but I can't seem to find in the core method that removes aros_acos records.

The problem I am having is if I use `$this->Acl->allow()` it creates a record.

However `$this->Acl->deny()` doesn't delete the record. It merely marks it as denied (Which is fine, if you are looking to explicitly deny Aco's.)

Because my default action is to deny all unless there is an allow record in the aros_acos, I don't need those records, and on a larger project, this table is going to fill up quickly. Is there a method to remove those records? Or is this something I am going to have to do "manually"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to mange the roles in wide level then use the [CakePHP Acl Manage](http://www.alaxos.net/blaxos/pages/view/plugin_acl_2.0/page:2) plugin for manage roles for users or group.

Comment: Appreciated. With the size of my project, this plugin is not efficient enough for my needs. This also does not answer my question.

Comment: I was just suggesting you to use. I think there is no any such type of methods provided in the code files of [Acl](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-DbAcl.html)(link for cakephp 2.3) to remove those unwanted records so you have to do it manually.